# html5 button background image states

Tags: css, html

I have a button and im trying to apply this image to its background, the green is the off state and yellow is the on click state.  Can I use this image where both states are in same file or do I need to separate them? What is the standard for this situation and how does the css work?

[image]

```
<button>click me</button>
button {
    background-image:url('button.png');
}
```

Comment: You could create a sprite image and use that. See this: http://davidwalsh.name/css-sprites . You could also look for tools that help you generate the css for them so you don't need to hardcode the offsets.

Comment: Is your button as simple as the example in your question? If so, you likely want to just use text and CSS as opposed to an image. Images are less accessible than plain text, especially background images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use button:focus for click state. Just declared it on css.

```
<button>Click me</button>
```

CSS sample :

```
button {
    background:yellow;
    padding:12px 40px;
    border:1px solid yellow;
    color:#454545;
}
button:focus {
    background:blue;
}
```

Just change color value on background with your background image path.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nucleo1985/fJ4g5/)

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can definitely use them. They're called CSS Sprites.

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jys3q/1/)**

```
button{
    width:196px;
    height:64px;
    background-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSVeQ.gif");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
button:active{
    background-position:0px -64px;
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right @TravisJ, I mis-calculated. Thank you. I'll edit.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is easiest to separate them into two files (e.g., FirstBackground.png and SecondBackground.png). Then you can use the following CSS:

```
button {
  background: url("/images/FirstBackground.png") no-repeat bottom;
}

button:active { 
    background: url(/images/SecondBackground.png) no-repeat bottom; 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, its like sprites... you can use the position in de background iamge like this

**Html:**

```
<button> </button>  <!-- Without the "Click Me" -->
```

**Css:**

```
button {
    background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSVeQ.gif');
    height:64px;
    width:196px;
}

button:active {background-position: 0 -64px; }
```

When the image has an height of 128px, give it 64px and use position when hovering or other state...

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zejx4/1)**

Answer (score 2):

### CSS Sprites

As noted by other answers, when dealing with buttons that have various states, and are dependent on the use of image resources, CSS sprites are often a good idea. For some examples, and commentary as to why the CSS sprites technique is useful, I recommend checking out the following article from CSS-Tricks: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

### Is it necessary to use images at all?

I am assuming the example image in your question is a bit contrived. If not, I would suggest not using background images for this at all. CSS today is very powerful and you can use it to craft very nice buttons that do not require images at all. If you're looking to use some simple background colors, gradient, rounded corners, etc. -- those are all possible with CSS alone. Also, a text/CSS solution for the button increases its accessibility.

Comment: Great explained answer.